# Applications of using ! vs ~ in loop conditions

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, verilog, logical-operators, reduction

In Verilog I have noticed that various resources (course notes vs. online resources) tend to use either the logical operator !, or the reduction operator ~ within the condition of an if statement.

For example, using this with an active-low reset:

```
if(!reset)

//reset statements, etc.
```

or

```
if(~reset)

//reset statements, etc.
```

I believe they both essentially give the same simulation result, thanks to knowing that the reset SHOULD/WOULD be a 1-bit binary input of 1 or 0. I understand that this may change if the condition were a multiple bit value.

Would there be any application benefit of selecting one over the other? Any examples someone could provide? What would be the changes with respect to synthesis? Simulation?

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this question might have some opinionated biases, but I expect the expression you put in an `if(expression)` to be evaluated as a 1-bit true or false result. So `!result` is more representative of your intent.

Answer (score 0):

For a single bit signal, such as your reset, yes they should give the same result in simulation and synthesis. Any tool that doesn't *likely* has some bug.

I personally don't believe one is better than the other. I have seen both used in successful designs for years in FPGA and ASIC. I generally use ~ as I prefer to think of a set/reset that is active low having a true inverter on the set/reset pin.